# How to handle Voip calls in background in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, voip

I had a webrtc connection that's works fine when app is in foreground , but when app is in background the audio disconnect.
I believe i am missing something as it works in a lot of voip apps with no special permission

I read about schedule a background task but i think this is meant to execute something periodic ever x minutes , not to handle a call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) to pass the call information to the system.

There are some packages

- [flutter_callkit_incoming](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming)
- [flutter_callkit](https://github.com/voximplant/flutter_callkit)

that try to deal with this issue, but you may need to adapt it to your own needs, e.g. by forking or getting some inspiration from their implementation (maybe [this article](https://faun.pub/using-ios-callkit-7ffd260e80d4) will help) if that doesn't match your use case. In the past I implemented VoIP calling app with Flutter and I had to use CallKit manually in Swift.

Comment: Does it work in background , as it my problem now that audio cut when app is in background , not the screen itself , and this is in outbound to be clear

Comment: it really help doing fork and got some inspiration from the projects

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an VoIP capability to maintain a connection in the background. See the Signing & Capabilities pane in you app configuration, select Background modes, and enable "Voice over IP."

That said, I recommend exploring the full documentation on handling VoIP via [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit). You'll generally want more than just enabling a background mode.

Comment: i already added all capability , to be clear i use webrtc as in janus